# How to use Mockito to verify that an error message is logged?

Tags: java, logging, mocking, mockito

I have an error condition that I want to test. The behavior I want to verify is that an error message gets written to the log. Since Mockito can't stub static methods, this is rather difficult, because I want my class-under-test to either write directly to `System.err.println()` or my static `Log.error()` method. I don't want to have to inject a mocked "logger object" into every single object that might write error messages!

So I guess what I'm asking is, what do you think is the best way to structure my Log class and/or the class-under-test so that I can stub out the logging methods or replace them with a mocked logger?

The best answer might not even make use of Mockito, it could be anything. I'd rather not import yet another library like PowerMock, but if you have a good answer that requires something like that I wouldn't mind seeing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to keep your logging logic in static methods, you can still initialize real logging implementation when the class is loaded based on some system property:

```
class Log {

  private static MyLogger logger;

  static {
    String className = System.getProperty("my.static.logger.class.name");
    // Instantiate your logger here...
    // By default use some DefaultLogger implementation...
  }

  public static void error(String message, Throwable t) {
    logger.error(message, t);
  }

}
```

Then when you run your test you can specify a mock class name using -D property. But you will need to implement your mock logging class without mockito magic.

Comment: Right, I was trying to think of ways to inject the logging dependency. This way isn't half bad since it can be specified on the command line if I want. But as you said, instantiating by reflection also means I can't inject a Mockito mock.

Comment: I guess if I wanted to inject a mock at runtime I'd need to have a `Log.setLogger()` method. I can't really think of a nicer way to do that. And I'd have to make that method public because my tests won't all be in the same package as the `Log` class. Meh.